# R) Create double-labeled MDS plot

Tags: r, plot

I am totally new to R. 
I have expression profile data which is preprocessed and combined. Looks like this ("exp.txt")

```
       STUDY_1_CANCER_1   STUDY_1_CON_1   STUDY_2_CANCER_1  STUDY_2_CANCER_2
P53    1.111              1.22             1.3               1.4
.....
```

Also, I created phenotype data. Looks lite this ("pheno.txt")

```
Sample               Disease        Study
STUDY_1_CANCER_1     Cancer         GSE1
STUDY_1_CON_1        Normal         GSE1
STUDY_2_CANCER_1     Cancer         GSE2
STUDY_2_CON_1        Normal         GSE2
```

Here, I tried to make MDS plot using classical cmdscale command like this.

```
data=read.table("exp.txt", row.names=1, header=T)
DATA=as.matrix(data)
pc=cor(DATA, method="p")
mds=cmdscale(as.dist(1-pc),2)
plot(mds)
```

[image]

I'd like to create plot like this figure with color double-labeling (Study and Disease). How should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create an empty plot, then add the points with specified colors/shapes.

Here's an example:

```
require(vegan)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)

mds <- cmdscale(vegdist(dune, method='bray'))


# set colors and shapes
cols = c('red', 'blue', 'black', 'steelblue')
shps = c(15, 16, 17)
# empty plot
plot(mds, type = 'n')
# add points
points(mds, col = cols[dune.env$Management], pch = shps[dune.env$Use])
# add legend
legend('topright', col=cols, legend=levels(dune.env$Management), pch = 16, cex = 0.7)
legend('bottomright', legend=levels(dune.env$Use), pch = shps, cex = 0.7)
```

Note that factors are internally coded as integers, which is helpful here.

```
> levels(dune.env$Management)
[1] "BF" "HF" "NM" "SF"
```

so

```
cols[dune.env$Management]
```

will take the first entry of `cols` for the first factor levels. Similariy for the different shapes.

Finally add the legend. Of course this plot still needs some polishing, but thats the way to go...

BTW: Gavin Simpson has a nice [blogpost](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2012/04/11/customising-vegans-ordination-plots/) about customizing ordination plots.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do this directly in default `plot` command which can take `pch` and `col` arguments as vectors. Use:

```
with(data, plot(mds, col = as.numeric(Study), pch = as.numeric(Disease), asp = 1)
```

You **must** use `asp = 1` when you plot `cmdscale` results: both axes **must** be scaled similarly. You can also add `xlab` and `ylab` arguments for nicer axis labels. For adding legend and selecting plotting characters and colours, see other responses.